# pytesseract not idenfiying digits properly as well it is detecting dashed 0 as 8

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

Pytesseract unable to identify proper characters as well it is predicting slashed zero wrong.

Here is my Image:
[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('dilation_1_0.png') #dilation_1.png working,eroded.png,eroded_1.png

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config="--psm 6 oem 0")

print(text)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You should train your tesseract.

Comment: Hi , I have trained twice but not detecting still , cropped that image manually , once i  do cropping using opencv , it unables to identify any character

Comment: This could be useful: [How to Distinguish Slashed Zero From Eight (0->8) in OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312408)

Answer (score 0):

For any image, you need to **preprocess** it make it detect more easily
some methods are

- 1.grayscale image
- 2.erosion
- 3.opening - erosion followed by dilation
- 4.canny edge detection
- 5.skew correction
- 6.template matching

Choose which one works best for you, or you can do it in combinations. Check the following link for detailed explanations
[Preprocessing for Pytesseract](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/#preprocessingfortesseract)

NB;Make sure you installed tesseract.exe also. If it is working for normal text images, your tesseract.exe is installed(this is different from pytessearct)

Comment: Template matching wont work in this case because this is dot matrix 8*8 pixel format characters , i have been working closely on your methods , the issue is i am unable to find proper perspective of the display of machine and canny edge works different in every image , do you have any thing in your mind that i can do so called generalized canny edges detection (means it will extract same part from different images taking from different angles ) ?

Comment: Extract same part is easy, u can slice that particular part if the object remains at the same position.  If the images are similar, u can subtract the new image from the original image to get the difference and perform operations https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/. If you want more advanced you can try EAST TEXT DETECTION https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/.  Other than this check about transformations in opencv.